# How to block certain websites with TP-Link AX1800

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have an LG smart TV that I would like to block ads for, so I'm trying to block all the URLs mentioned on this [site](https://techpenny.com/how-to-block-ads-on-a-smart-tvs/). This seems to be easy to do by following [TPLink's instructions for using Access Control to block websites](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/1387/). However, the interface for the AX1800 looks different than what I can find instructions for and despite all my searching, I can't find how to do it. I read through the [Access Control portion of the AX1800 user guide](https://www.tp-link.com/us/user-guides/archer-ax20&ax1800_v1/chapter-10-network-security#ug-sub-title-2) and it looks like this refers to blocking *devices*, not websites. Is it possible that they have removed this feature, or am I just missing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The
[AX1800 WiFi 6 Router manual](https://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/RAX20/RAX20_UM_EN.pdf)
specifies on page 43 how to "Use keywords to block Internet sites":

- Enter the config at *ADVANCED > Security > Block Sites*
- Set blocking option to Always
- In "Type keyword or domain name here" field, enter the domain to block.
  For example the first on the list: `config.samsungads.com`
- Click "Add Keyword"
- Click Apply
- Continue for all the other addresses.

(Note: I have been using a Samsung SmartTV for years, and I never saw a single ad.)